# Rasbian lite does not assign dhcp IP address

Tags: raspbian, dhcp, raspi-config

I have an issue with Rasbian lite.

I downloaded the OS and installed it in a Raspberry PI Model 3B.
logged in and typed the following:

- `sudo raspi-config`
- added wifi access point name and password
- saved and finished

this closed the raspi-config tool

I then typed `ifconfig`

ifconfig shows the Wlan0 without an IP address

```
wlan0 : flags=4099,UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>.   mtu 1500
      ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx. txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
      RX packets 0.  bytes. 0. (0.0B)
      RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 fram 0
      TX packets 0. bytes 0. (0.0B)
      TX errors 0 dropped 0 overrun 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

There is suppose to be a line that read :

```
inet 169.123.1.netmask 255.255.255.0
```

This is not in the ifconfig.

I cannot ping a local or internet IP address
I do not have access to the internet.

I tested the hardware and the network credentials using the rasbian OS with Desktop.  That worked.

- The hardware works
- The WIFI credentials work
- The full version of Rasbian works...Not the Lite version.

Why is this error happening when I attempt to use Rasbian lite (Stretch and buster)?

Comment: You must have done something wrong, but **The WIFI credentials work** is meaningless; you need to list the contents of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (you can obfuscate your password). PS do not use ifconfig use `ip a`

Comment: I always use "$ hostname -I" to get the ip addresses.  My head is too small to remember other methods, like looking into /etc/..., /boot... or other "$ abc" commands which work for raspbian wheezy but no longer jessie, or jessie ok but no longer stretch, and of course stretch Ok but sorry, not for buster.  And also full version ok but not lite, and lite ok but not full version, or full version ok but no full version with recommended software.  I started to keep a record of setup/init/config notes each os version, but I found the notes I wrote earlier no longer useful, some  became plain wrong.

Comment: I need help with the intent of the question. Sorry, these comments do not offer me any I can try.

Comment: as first comment says ... show the contents of `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` (hide your ssid/password if you want)

Comment: To elaborate it a bit more: please open a linux terminal so you can execute commands on the command line. Then execute this command: `sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. This should output the contents of that file. You can select this text output with your mouse and copy and paste it into your question that you have opened for editing (there's a link under it) in your browser.

Comment: @Spineless It seems you may have lost your original logic credentials and created another account with the same name.  If you wish to merge them, see *["I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?"](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)*.

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned in the comments, you should use `ip addr` instead of `ifconfig`.

Your `ifconfig` output doesn't show the `RUNNING` flag. The output of `ip addr` (or `ip link`) would probably not include the `LOWER_UP` flag. That means that contrary to your claims the WLAN is not connected, therefor it can't obtain an IP address.